# Allocating memory for struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a fairly simple question on allocating memory for a struct in c and I've tried looking online, but I wasn't able to find anything. The struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct cblock_ {
....
} cblock, *Cblock;
```

When allocating memory, I've tried

```
Cblock new_block = malloc(sizeof(struct cblock_));
```

However, I keep getting getting a memory corruption error. I've tried changing the parameter of sizeof to different things, but everything is getting the same memory corruption error. What am I doing wrong?

******EDIT******

So after running valgrind, I am getting quite a bit of "invalid write of size 4" or "invalid read of size 4" throughout my code.

It's probably too much to post all of it but here's one spot where valgrinds gives me a "invalid write of size 4"

```
static Ablock agroup_main;    

typedef struct ablock_ {
    int length;
    int num;
    ...
} ablock, *Ablock;

void init_groups() {
    agroup_main = malloc(sizeof(Ablock));

    agroup_main->length = DEFAULT_GROUP_LENGTH;
    agroup_main->num = DEFAULT_GROUP_NUM;

}
```

Valgrind is saying on the line setting length that it's an invalid write of size 4, and the address is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd. For num, it's the same except the address is 4 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd. I don't really understand this either, since length is just an int, and to me, the error sounds like I'm suppose to allocate memory for it...

Comment: If possible, show more code, and give more information about your compilation command, your operating system, your whole software...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory corruption is probably because of an *earlier* incorrect `malloc` (e.g. with a too small size), premature `free`, or genuine buffer overflow (or uninitialized pointer dereference).

Use a memory leak detector. On Linux, try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org)

Your `malloc` for `Cblock` looks ok. The bug is probably elsewhere. Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`). Use also a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). You might want to disable [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to ease debugging (and have more reproducible runs).

You should test the result of `malloc`:

```
cblock* new_block = malloc(sizeof(struct cblock_));
if (!new_block) { 
    perror("malloc cblock"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

and I think you should mark clearly all the pointers in your code (so I prefer `cblock*` instead of `Cblock` which I find confusing, and which should at least be named `CblockPtr`).

BTW, you have been bitten by that confusion:

```
    agroup_main = malloc(sizeof(Ablock));  // WRONG!
```

is incorrect, since `Ablock` is a pointer type (on Linux/PC, all pointers have the same size, which is 8 bytes on x86-64). You mean

```
    agroup_main = malloc(sizeof(ablock));
    if (!agroup_main) 
       { perror("malloc ablock"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You really should loose the bad habit of naming pointer types in a way hiding their pointerness (and with a name similar to the *pointed* data).

Comment: This is probably correct. The fact that OP has tried different sizes when calling malloc indicates the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: `Cblock` is an alias for `struct cblock_ *` type. The `*` is not needed.

Comment: I know that, but marking all pointers is IMHO important. So `Cblock` is less readable than `cblock*` : you need to convey to the reader of your code that some variable is -or not- a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
agroup_main = malloc(sizeof(Ablock));
```

is clearly wrong, since the type `Ablock` is `struct ablock_ *`, i.e. *a pointer*. You're just allocating the size of the pointer, not the size of the object being pointed at.

You should always write it like this:

```
agroup_main = malloc(sizeof *agroup_main);
```

that uses `sizeof` on the proper type, the type that the pointer receiving the return value points at.

I also stronly recommend *against* `typedef`ing away the pointer like that, since it adds confusion. Pointers are important in C, hiding them often makes things harder to understand and follow, thus increasing the risk of error. The question "is this an object, or a pointer to an object?" is very important, and you must be able to answer it quickly and correctly, all the time.

Comment: Btw, I see now that the second half of @BasileStarynkevitch's answer is pretty much identical to this. D'oh.